# Cordova ios -Your ios platform does not have Api.js in old project

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

When we run cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
command ,I have got error "Your ios platform does not have Api.js". Because I have a old project in ios cordova.

Is the any way to add plugin manually.

Comment: When we try to add plugin manually the got error-  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.InAppBrowser.open')

Answer (score 0):

You should update the cordova-ios version of your project or downgrade the Cordova CLI to use an older version that included the cordova-ios version you have in the project.

You can also try to install the plugins with `--nofetch` param at the end.